# esxi 5.0 Command Line, no disown command

Tags: ssh, vmware-esxi, job-control

In linux I would use the disown command to disconnect a backgrounded process from my terminal so when I quit the terminal or disconnected from it, the job would continue as a child of the init process.  In the ESXi /bin/sh shell, I see no disown command.  How can I disown a running process in the shell of an esxi host?  Using ssh to connect.

Comment: What's your use case here? You should really not be running any long-running processes in the ESXi console.

Answer (score 2):

ESXi uses a limited console based on a customized version of [Busybox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BusyBox) and only features a subset of the tools you'd see in a traditional Linux installation. It's a single executable with multiple hard-links to the main binary.

You should not be running any "jobs" on the ESXi console. Why do you require this functionality?

Comment: Say I started a vmkfstools disk clone via ssh, and it was running after I needed to leave the office and take my laptop, thus disconnecting from the ssh session.  It would be nice to disown that process.  If I had known it was going to run so long, I could have nohupped it, but I didn't.  Doesn't seem like too much to ask.

Comment: You don't have access to Virtual Center?

Comment: Lots of small setups don't use Virtual Center. Hey, guess what I'm doing later today? Migrating some machines off ESXi by hand... somehow.

Comment: @MikeyB VMWare Converter.

Comment: The vCenter barrier isn't particularly high, even for small standalone systems (The Essentials package is ~$500US). But if you're at the point where you're cloning VMDKs with `vmkfstools` commands, it may make sense to have access to a Virtual Center. Migration of VMs from standalone hosts can be handled by vCenter Converter or just an .ovf export, though.

Comment: There is NO money in the budget, I was lucky to get the server for the ESX host.  Of course, anyone in my situation would probably like an answer to my question, but they will just come here and see downvotes and disdain instead :)  Also, they are symlinks, not hardlinks ( I can tell because they have different inodes)

Comment: @GreggLeventhal I didn't downvote... but if you're in this situation, I'd recommend connecting from a Linux server through a `screen` or `tmux` session if you anticipate a long-running process on an ESXi host.

Comment: I wasn't saying you did, but I am just voicing my frustration with the downvoting of reasonable questions, simply because someone else doesn't use the product in the same way.  I am working for a major electronics manufacturer, and am a professional linux admin, but that doesn't mean I get a 10 host ESXi cluster with vCenter and a netApp.  I have 2 standalone hosts with ESXi free and an internal RAID datastore. :(  Not a bad idea to screen the ssh session from another linux box.  My laptop is windows, so I was using Cygwin to ssh, but what you say makes sense for this problem.

Comment: @GreggLeventhal The vSphere client can clone VMDKs by browsing the datastore and selecting it.

Comment: @NathanC I do not see a clone option, I have rename, delete, download, inflate, add to inventory..

Comment: @GreggLeventhal Copy + Paste = clone

Comment: I see what you mean, but how does that help me for this issue?  If I get disconnected from the network on the box that vsphere client issues the paste command on while it is still copying over, won't it kill the process that is copying the file over causing it to fail?

Answer (score 1):

This does work on ESXi 6.0:

```
exec </dev/null >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

This command explicitly closes stdin, stdout and stderr file descriptors, which will terminate your shell and SSH session, but e.g. leave a background file copy running.